# xslt : XSLT document('') function doesn't work for my code

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am not XSLT expert, in my below xslt code, trying to extract values from xml string as below.

**XML input as string:**

```
==========================================================================
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RootElement xmlns="http://com.nt.int/NT/v1.0/CustomInputs">
   <stringFlag><RESPONSE><RESULT>
        <RESPONSECODE>20000</RESPONSECODE>
        <MESSAGE>Successfully Received Revenue Information</MESSAGE>
        <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
    </RESULT>
</RESPONSE>
</stringFlag>  
</RootElement>
==================================================
```

**XSLT Stylesheet code as below:**

```
 <xsl:template match="/">

  <xsl:variable name="test">
<xsl:copy-of select="/ns0:RootElement/ns0:stringFlag"/></xsl:variable>  
 <xsl:variable name="vTestNodeset" select="document('')/*/*/xsl:variable[@name='test']"/>

 <xsl:variable name="var1" select="string($vTestNodeset/stringFlag/RESPONSE/RESULT/RESPONSECODE)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="var2" select="string($vTestNodeset/stringFlag/RESPONSE/RESULT/MESSAGE)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="var3" select="string($test/RESPONSE/RESULT/STATUS)"/>
        <output1><xsl:value-of select="$var1"/></output1>
        <output2><xsl:value-of select="$var2"/></output2>                     
        <output3><xsl:value-of select="$var3"/></output3>         
   </xsl:template>
```

**Expecting XML output as below**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output1>20000 </output1>
 <output2>Successfully Received Revenue Information </output2>
 <output3>OK</output3>
```

Iam unable to get the result as expected.Tried the possible ways I knew,but not helpful. Please need some help,Thank you.

Comment: Please review: [mcve].

Comment: Your problem is still not reproducible using your code. There is no such thing as "*XML input **as string***". If your input is not a well-formed XML document, you cannot parse it using XPath.

Answer (score 0):

> But vTestNodeset is always empty, Iam thinking that
>   select="document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='test']" is not executed as
>   expected.

No, the reason it is empty is that the `$test` variable is a child of `xsl:template` and a grandchild of `xsl:styleshet` (not shown in your snippet) - so the correct path to it would be:

```
document('')/*/*/xsl:variable[@name='test']
```

---

There could be additional reasons why it's empty. We don't have a fully reproducible example here. But if you reduce the code to the minimum required:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="test">TEST</xsl:variable> 
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="document('')/*/*/xsl:variable[@name='test']"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you should obtain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>TEST</result>
```

as the result.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I tried the document('')/*/*/xsl:variable[@name='test'] ,but not helpful...

Comment: Well, it works for me when I try it. As I said, you have too many other things going on.

Comment: Michael, Your code works fine,but mine doesn't,cant figure it out,I added the whole xsl file,could you please take a look, thanks in advance.

Comment: the value of $test below is not being assigned to the variable vTestNodeset: 
  <stringFlag><RESPONSE><RESULT>
        <RESPONSECODE>20000</RESPONSECODE>
        <MESSAGE>Successfully Received Revenue Information</MESSAGE>
        <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
    </RESULT>
</RESPONSE>
         </stringFlag>

Comment: Please minimize you example and include an example of the input, too. -- If this is related to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918217/xslt-converting-string-to-xml-node-using-xslt), then the problem is that you are trying to parse escaped XML as if it were XML. It is not.

Comment: Michael, I gave the input above.Its a string in this form,trying to extract each element's value and assigning to target: 
   <RESPONSE>    <RESULT><RESPONSECODE>10000</RESPONSECODE>
        <MESSAGE>Successfully Received</MESSAGE>
        <STATUS>OK</STATUS>
        </RESULT>
        </RESPONSE>

Comment: @Ramzi I am afraid I cannot follow this. Please stop posting code in comments and edit your question in such way that your problem can be **easily** reproduced.

Comment: Michael, I simplified my question, hope its helpful  this time in understanding my problem.